# JavaScript changes font-weight for no reason?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

Got a bit of a weird issue with a site I'm working on. When I load the homepage my fonts found within the navigation and headings seem to loose some font-weight for some reason. I've managed to narrow it down to a small piece of javascript that only loads on the homepage, when removed all my fonts are nice and fat.

In the javascript (made for a slider) it doesn't mention h tags at all, or anything to do with font-weight. But yet it still seems to be effecting it.

Here's the JS, if anyone can see why this might be happening?

```
var sliderActive = $("#wrapper #slider-single")

sliderActive.not(":first").removeClass("active");

sliderActive.on("hover", function() {
    sliderActive.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

That's it. Like I say, if I remove this file the fonts are fine. No idea why :S

The CSS for the class active affects the slider you see here: http://ember.lukeseager.com

```
.active .each {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-transition: .3s ease; -webkit-transition: .3s ease; 
    -o-transition: .3s ease; -ms-transition: .3s ease; transition: .3s ease;
}
.active .home_video {
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Any info you guys have would be amazing!
Thanks!

EDIT: 
Testing this across browsers, it seems to just be an issue on Chrome (only tested on Mac so far). Maybe it's just a browser rendering issue?

Comment: could it be because, you forgot semicolon in the first line?

Comment: What's the CSS for class `active`?

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick reply! Unfortunately this hasn't fixed the issue :/

Comment: Adding the CSS code to the question can speed up your chances of correct response.

Comment: The CSS is simply for a slider, it changes background colour, has a transition on it, changes absolute positioning top and z-index :)

Comment: What are “h tags” that lose font weight, and how did you infer that they do so?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that the CSS class `.active` is defined to have another font-weight. SO when you add that class, the font-weight changes. Please double check your CSS via a Code Inspector after the script was executed.

Comment: Posted the CSS. Unfortunately the .active class doesn't have any typographic styling at all :/

Comment: @lucas572 Are you sure this is the only definition loaded? Have you checked fire a live inspector tool? (e.g. Chrome Inspector, Opera Dragonfly or Firefox Firebug)

Answer (score 0):

It's in the http://ember.lukeseager.com/wp-content/themes/ember/css/reset.css file:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-size:100%; font-weight:normal }
```

UPDATE:

Are you sure it's font-weight you're talking about, and not font-size?  typography.css contains:

```
.slider-heading { font-size: 1em !important; }
```

The `!important` flag makes this override the following from layout.css:

.each h2 { font-size: 18px; }

Comment: Just removed this, hasn't changed the weight though :/

Comment: Which elements are you talking about? I just inspected the page and all the `<H2>` elements are bold.

Comment: Literally all of my fonts (apart from the paragraph fonts). If you compare the navigation to the other pages you'll see it's much thinner, and also the headings "LATEST TWEET" and "FOLLOW US" are much thinner. The same can be said for the headings within the slider itself.

Comment: See my upate regarding font-size.

Comment: Yea that's an intentional change of font size. 

I'm assuming it's font-weight because if you hard refresh the home page you can see the navigation flash bold then change to it's final state of what looks like a normal weight font. 

If you compare this to every other page the difference is very noticeable :/

Comment: I think I see what you're talking about now. That could be the font size changing from 1.3em to 1em.  At the same time, the highlight color in the tweet is changing from reddish to orange, maybe there's a relationship.

Comment: Edited original post, only happens in Chrome. Maybe a browser rendering issue?